# Tailwind css group hover animation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm a newbie to tailwind css. Hover animation doesn't work in this case. When someone hovers over the group, I want the background to be animated, however that isn't happening; instead, the background color is always displayed.

```html
<li className=" text-gray  active:text-red group">
  <a href={`${href}`}>
    {name}
  </a>
  <div className="h-0.5 bg-red scale-x-0 group-hover:scale-100 transition-transform origin-left rounded-full duration-300 ease-out" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add group to the parent div for the group-hover to work in tailwind css.

```html
<li className="group text-gray  active:text-red group">
  <a href={`${href}`}>
    {name}
  </a>
  <div className="h-0.5 bg-red scale-x-0 group-hover:scale-100 transition-transform origin-left rounded-full duration-300 ease-out" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your animation to work, you have to close the `div` and put something into it ;-) For example like this, using your code snippet, in this case. More about `group-hover` [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states)

---

```
<li className="text-gray active:text-red group">
  <a href={`${href}`}>{name}</a>
  <div className="h-0.5 bg-red scale-x-0 group-hover:scale-100 transition-transform origin-left rounded-full duration-300 ease-out">
    It works!
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: you have to hover on bluet point, and than works perfectly.

Comment: I used Next.js with Tailwind Css for testing  my answer snippet code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it to your variant on `tailwind.config.js` file. Try this:

```
variants: {
    extend: {
      scale: ["group-hover"]
    },
  },
```